# Redhat or CentOS7 systemd may remove user IPC resources unexpectedly

Tags: authentication, ipc, redhat, centos7, systemd

According to the comment below, linux systemd can remove my IPC resources without my allowance.
I already met this problem during important PoC(Proof of concept) test.
But, I have difficulty in reproducing this problem in my desktop.
Is there anybody who encountered this problem before and knows the easy way to reproduce it?
In my case, system removed my semaphore, and most processes were still up and some processes using removed semaphores encountered crash.

=================================================================
https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-changes-between-versions/

RemoveIPC Directive

A new option called RemoveIPC was introduced in RHEL 7.2 through Systemd v219.
When set to yes, this option forces a cleanup of all allocated inter-process communication (IPC) resources linked to a user leaving his last session.
If a daemon is running as a user with a uid number >=1000, it may crash.

This option should always be set to no by default but, due to the logic of package upgrade, it is highly advisable to set RemoveIPC=no in the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file followed by # systemctl restart systemd-logind (source).

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out the way to reproduce RemoveIPC problem.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf |grep RemoveIPC
RemoveIPC=yes

$ systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

---

```
1. remember there is no semaphore yet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─root@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems    

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. loginctl list-sessions 
    (just one session exist in logind session list - root user)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─dplee@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION   UID USER         SEAT           
         1           0     root           seat0          
   1 sessions listed.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. RemoveIPC = yes, check if systemd-logind is up
    (set RemoveIPC = yes in /etc/systemd/logind.conf and execute "systemctl restart systemd-logind")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─root@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep RemoveIPC
RemoveIPC=yes

╭─root@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ ps -ef | grep systemd | grep login
root       923     1  0 12:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. change user to dplee2 and start semaphore creation process.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─root@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ su - dplee2

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~ 
╰─$ cd work/test

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ cat t.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

union semun
{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short int *array;
};

static int  semid;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* fp;

    union semun sem_union;

    struct sembuf mysem_open  = {0, -1, SEM_UNDO};
    struct sembuf mysem_close = {0, 1, SEM_UNDO};
    int sem_num;

    sem_num = 1;

    semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, sem_num, 0600|IPC_CREAT);
    if (semid == -1)
    {
        perror("semget error ");
        return -1;
    }  

    sem_union.val = 1;
    if ( -1 == semctl( semid, 0, SETVAL, sem_union))
    { 
            printf( "semctl()-SETVAL 실행 오류\n");
            return -1;
    } 

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 1;
}

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ nohup ./a.out &
[1] 4602
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'                                                                                                                                                         

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
5. check if semaphore created successfully and process is up.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems    
0x00000000 229376     dplee2     600        1        

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ps -ef | grep dplee2 | grep a.out
dplee2    4602  4537  0 12:30 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
5. still just one session is in session list : root user (not dplee2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION    UID USER             SEAT           
         1            0     root              seat0          
   1 sessions listed.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. create one more session (dplee2 user) through another window.
     (dplee2 session is SESSION id 3 as below)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ ssh dplee2@192.168.0.33

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION    UID USER             SEAT           
         1               0  root               seat0          
         3       1005  dplee2                          
   2 sessions listed.


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
7. semaphore still exists and process is also still up.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems    
0x00000000 229376     dplee2     600        1        

╭─dplee2@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ps -ef | grep dplee2 | grep a.out
dplee2    4602  4537  0 12:30 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
8. close the second window (dplee2 user session) or log out.
    (or just execute "loginctl terminate-session 3" command)
   Then, dplee2 session is gone. (Only root user(the first logged in session) exists) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─root@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ loginctl list-sessions          
   SESSION      UID USER             SEAT           
         1                0   root               seat0          
   1 sessions listed.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
9. process is still up and the semaphore is gone. <-- removed by system
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

╭─root@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ps -ef | grep dplee2 | grep a.out
dplee2    4602  4537  0 12:30 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out

╭─root@localhost  ~/work/test 
╰─$ ipcs -s                         

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```